# Can someone prove about the measure of parallelepiped?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove a theorem, but I cannot do that. The theorem I will say is written in the textbook, but the leave the proof in exercise. :( I am almost frustrated because of my useless brain.... Hahh........ I really hope that someone prove the following theorem.

---

the closed ***parallelepiped***
$$P=\left\{ \mathbf{x} : \mathbf{x} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} t_ke_k, 0\le t_k \le 1 \right\}$$
where $e_k$ are parallel to the coordinate axes.

---

the ***volume of the interval*** $I=\{(x_1, \cdots, x_n): a_k\le x_k \le b_k, k=1, \cdots, n\}$
$$v(I)=\prod_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k)$$

---

### Theorem

If $P$ is a parallelepiped, then
$$|P|=v(P)$$
where $|P|$ is the absolute value of the $n \times n$ determinant whose rows are the edges of $P$.

---

I am able to prove the theorem if $n$ is less than or equal to 3, that is in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R^3}$. However, I cannot generalize that in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Please help me.

Comment: SHoaw that the claim holds if $P$ is spanned by the standard base in any order. Then show that the claim is invarant under multiplication with elementary matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll present a sketch of a proof and leave a few lemmata for you to prove.

Consider the $n$-cube formed by the standard basis. We can prove that this has measure $1$ the same way we prove that the unit interval has measure $1$. Next prove that a parallelepiped is the image of this cube under a matrix transformation, $\alpha$. Specifically, this matrix is the one whose columns define the sides of the parallelepiped.

This matrix has $\det$ equal to the volume of the parallelepiped, which is a widely know fact, or you can prove it yourself. To complete the proof, you need to prove that if $A$ is a matrix and $m$ is a measurable set, then $$\mu(A*m)=\det(A)\mu(m)$$ where "$A*m$" represents the image of the set $m$ under the action of $A$. The intuition here is that if we write $A=\det(A)A'$, then $\det(A)$ is the scaling part and $A'$ is the rotation and translation part, so the measure should be invariant under $A'$ and the total action of the matrix should just be scaling.

Once you've proven these facts, you can say that the measure of the parallelepiped is equal to the measure of the cube times the determinant of the matrix $A$. But this is the determinant of $A$, since the cube has measure $1$. The determinant of $A$ is equal to the volume of the parallelepiped, so by the transitive property we are done.

Comment: Wow. I am afraid that I can prove although I get the perfect sketch. Very thank you.